# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. Error message with my sql statement

Tags: sql

I am getting this error while trying to Insert some data in my database.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint `FK_DevID_Prog`. The conflict occurred in database `ElectricImp`, table `dbo.Developer`, column `DevID`.

Code:

```
Create Table Developer
(
    DevID       Char(10)    Not Null,
    UserName    Char(20)    Not Null,
    DevPassword Char(20)    Not Null,
    Email       VarChar(20) Not Null,
    Country     VarChar(25) Not Null,
    ZipCode     Integer,
    CellPhone   Integer     Not Null,
    Constraint PK_DevID Primary Key(DevID)
);

--Drop Table Programme;
Create Table Programme
(
    ProgrammeID     Char(10)    Not Null,
    DevID           Char(10)    Not Null,
    ProgrammeName   VarChar(20) Not Null,
    ProgrammeCode   VarChar(20) Not Null,
    Constraint PK_ProgID Primary Key(ProgrammeID),
    Constraint FK_DevID_Prog Foreign Key(DevID) References Developer(DevID)

Insert Into 
Developer(DevID,UserName,DevPassword,Email,Country,ZipCode,CellPhone)
Values
    ('Dev123456A','Paul Wilson Diu','P@ulWilson','Paul_Wilson@yahoo.com','Philippines','12345','0277824893'),
    ('Dev123456B','Actor One','@ctor1','Actor_One@yahoo.com','New Zealand','11234','0293847567'),
    ('Dev123456C','Actor Two','@ctor2','Actor_Two@yahoo.com','USA','42562','028394576'),
    ('Dev123456D','Actor Three','@ctor3','Actor_Three@yahoo.com','USA','93847','0294857689'),
    ('Dev123456E','Actor Four','@ctor4','Actor_Four@yahoo.com','Australia','02947','0293847563'),
    ('Dev123456F','Actor Five','@ctor5','Actor_Five@gmail.com','Germany','92846','0293748123');

Insert Into 
Programme(ProgrammeID,DevID,ProgrammeName,ProgrammeCode)
Values
    ('Prog12345A','Dev123456A','Programme A','ProgCode123A'),
    ('Prog12345B','Dev123456B','Programme B','ProgCode123B'),
    ('Prog12345C','Dev123456A','Programme C','ProgCode123C'),
    ('Prog12345D','Dev123456C','Programme D','ProgCode123D'),
    ('Prog12345E','Dev123456B','Programme E','ProgCode123E'),
    ('Prog12345F','Dev123456D','Programme F','ProgCode123F'),
    ('Prog12345G','Dev123456C','Programme G','ProgCode123G'),
    ('Prog12345H','Dev123456E','Programme H','ProgCode123H');
```

Comment: Check that there's no conflicts currently, then drop the FK add the data and add the FK back in.

Comment: What DBMS is this? I'm guessing probably SQL Server given the use of dbo. Might help to add that into the question.

Comment: I tried your records in the fiddle an it worked perfectly. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c27e/1

Answer (score 4):

your data insert into Developer table failed, so don't have any record in Developer table. And when you insert data into Programme table, Programme.DevID can not refer Developer.DevID

I tried your script insert data, and error occurs Developer table:

String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

'Paul_Wilson@yahoo.com' Len: 21 character, but Email field: VARCHAR(20) => Error

You can check again

Comment: Thanks I was able to make it work eventually.. thanks